# How to get response header in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http, http-headers

I try to get the headers from a http response if the error code is 401 for the digest auth.

This is my code:

```
 this.http.post(this.hostname + ':10000/users/auth2', { })
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Everything work's fine if the post request return a 200 code.
If I return a 401 code from the backend I cannot access the headers.

The chrome debugger shows the headers. Postman call also work's fine with digest auth.

Comment: As long as `error` is instanceof `HttpErrorResponse`, you should be able to check the headers: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse#constructor() since it extends https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponseBase . `error.headers` should be instance of https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders

Answer (score 2):

The default option for `observe` parameter is `body`, change it by 
adding `{observe: 'response'}` to your `post` method:

```
 this.http.post(this.hostname + ':10000/users/auth2', {}, {observe: 'response'})
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error.headers);
    });
```

Comment: I've added {observe: 'response'} to the request but the header filed is empty. headers: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null; normalizedNames: Map(0)

Comment: I guess it's a security issue in Chrome console. I guess you do get the headers you just can't print them to the console. try doing some code manipulations on the desired headers and let me know if it works

Comment: I tried to set the response headers as paypload to a new request
```this.http.post(this.hostname + ':10000/users/auth2', {  }, {observe: 'response'})
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log("TEST");
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error.headers);

                this.http.post(this.hostname + ':10000/users/test',error.headers , {headers:  error.headers}).subscribe(res => {
                    console.log("TEST");
                });
                
            });```

It doesn't work...

Comment: I use it in the following way to get a specific header maybe this should work for you:
`res.headers.get('<THE_DESIRED_HEADER_NAME>');`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, i wanted to get the status code from the response.

Ended up do something like that :

```
   return await this.http
        .post<any>(this.hostname + ':10000/users/auth2', {})
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.data, (err:HttpErrorResponse) => err.headers);
```